# Redirect Ecwid URLs with fragment identifiers to new Woocommerce URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo, woocommerce, redirect

I recently migrated a client's e-commerce site from Ecwid to WooCommerce. Ecwid's URL's use fragment identifiers which is now a problem as I can't set up a 301 redirect to the new URL using .htaccess. As I understand, everything past the # isn't accessible to .htaccess.

I'd like to try and preserve their SEO ranking as well as easily update all the old URLs to new.

There are dozens of Wordpress plugins which offer the ability to redirect pages, but I'm concerned I'll have the same issue. From what I've read Javascript redirects don't use the 301 response code, so search engines wouldn't know what the new URL is.

Is there any other way to redirect this:

```
example.com/products/#!/100-Cotton-Sash-Cord/p/19877065/category=4619310
```

to this?

```
example.com/shop/all-natural/100-cotton-sash-cord/
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, everything after the # isn't processed by the server.

However, if your old site was previously indexed completely by Google, you can presumably pick the ["ugly" URLs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more) for the snapshot pages and redirect those?